# Terraform loop : for_each

Tags: terraform, infrastructure-as-code

I need help to run **for_each** on terraform for following variable set

```
locals {
  db_users = {
    test_user1 = {      #user
      test_cluster1 = { #cluster
        db_name = ["db_a", "db_b", "db_c"]
        db_role = ["readWrite", "read", "readWrite"]
        db_type = ["CLUSTER", "CLUSTER", "CLUSTER"]
      },
      test_cluster2 = {
        db_name = ["db_a", "db_b", "db_c"]
        db_role = ["readWrite", "read", "readWrite"]
        db_type = ["CLUSTER", "CLUSTER", "CLUSTER"]
      }
    },
    test_user2 = {
      test_cluster1 = {
        db_name = ["db_d", "db_e", "db_f"]
        db_role = ["readWrite", "readWrite", "read"]
        #db_type = [["CLUSTER", "LAKE"], ["CLUSTER", "LAKE"], ["CLUSTER", "LAKE"]]
        db_type = ["CLUSTER", "CLUSTER", "CLUSTER"]
      },
      test_cluster2 = {
        db_name = ["db_d", "db_e", "db_f"]
        db_role = ["readWrite", "readWrite", "read"]
        db_type = ["CLUSTER", "CLUSTER", "CLUSTER"]
      }
    }
  }
```

The `db_type` can be both based on the situation. If we have multiple db_type then both value should be associated with the final resource.

I also tried **flatten** of the variable with following

```
value = flatten([
  for ip_key, ip in local.db_users : [
    for a, b in ip : [
      for index in range(length(b.db_name)) : {
        username = ip_key
        user_index = index
        roles = {
          role_name     = b.db_role[index]
          database_name = b.db_name[index]
        }
        scopes = {
          type = b.db_type[index]
          name = a
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
])
```

Output after flattening the value

```
[
  {
    "roles" = {
      "database_name" = "db_a"
      "role_name" = "readWrite"
    }
    "scopes" = {
      "name" = "test_cluster1"
      "type" = "CLUSTER"
    }
    "username" = "test_user1"
  },
  {
    "roles" = {
      "database_name" = "db_b"
      "role_name" = "read"
    }
    "scopes" = {
      "name" = "test_cluster1"
      "type" = "CLUSTER"
    }
    "username" = "test_user1"
  },
   ...
  {
    "roles" = {
      "database_name" = "db_d"
      "role_name" = "readWrite"
    }
    "scopes" = {
      "name" = "test_cluster1"
      "type" = "CLUSTER"
    }
    "username" = "test_user2"
  },
  {
    "roles" = {
      "database_name" = "db_e"
      "role_name" = "readWrite"
    }
    "scopes" = {
      "name" = "test_cluster1"
      "type" = "CLUSTER"
    }
    "username" = "test_user2"
  },
   ...
]
```

Looking into the type of the value, it is as follows

```
tuple([
    object({
        roles: object({
            database_name: string,
            role_name: string,
        }),
        scopes: object({
            name: string,
            type: string,
        }),
        username: string,
    }),
    ...
    object({
        roles: object({
            database_name: string,
            role_name: string,
        }),
        scopes: object({
            name: string,
            type: string,
        }),
        username: string,
    }),
])
```

**Question:**
What I want to achieve???

- I want to create the resource from this particular variable

The resource which is responsible for this is the following.
There can be as many **roles** and **scopes** in the same block as possible. For this we can you dynamic block setup

```
resource "users" "user" {
  username = var.username
  roles {
    database_name = var.database_name
    role_name     = var.role_name
  }
  roles {
    database_name = var.database_name
    role_name     = var.role_name
  }
  ...
  scopes {
    name = var.cluster
    type = var.type
  }
  scopes {
    name = var.cluster
    type = var.type
  }
  ...
}
```

and the resource should finally look like the following value.

```
Resource No. 1

username=test_user1
role = {
  db_name=db_a
  role=readWrite
}
role = {
  db_name=db_b
  role=read
}
role = {
  db_name=db_c
  role=readWrite
}
scope = {
  name = test_cluster1
  type = "cluster"
}
scope = {
  name = test_cluster1
  type = "lake"
}

Resource No. 2

username=test_user1
role = {
  db_name=db_d
  role=readWrite
}
role = {
  db_name=db_e
  role=read
}
role = {
  db_name=db_f
  role=readWrite
}
scope = {
  name = test_cluster2
  type = "cluster"
}
scope = {
  name = test_cluster2
  type = "lake"
}

Resource No. 3

username=test_user1
role = {
  db_name=db_a
  role=readWrite
}
role = {
  db_name=db_b
  role=read
}
role = {
  db_name=db_c
  role=readWrite
}
scope = {
  name = test_cluster1
  type = "cluster"
}
scope = {
  name = test_cluster1
  type = "lake"
}

Resource No. 4

username=test_user2
role = {
  db_name=db_d
  role=readWrite
}
role = {
  db_name=db_e
  role=read
}
role = {
  db_name=db_f
  role=readWrite
}
scope = {
  name = test_cluster2
  type = "cluster"
}
scope = {
  name = test_cluster2
  type = "lake"
}
```

Exact Source code used. ( I know this is not correct).
here `username`, `database_name`, `role_name`, `name`, and `type` all should be a string value

```
resource "users" "user" {
  for_each = local.db_users
  username = each.key
  dynamic "roles" {
    for_each = each.value
    content {
      database_name = each.value.db_name
      role_name     = each.value.db_role
    }
  }
  dynamic "scopes" {
    for_each = each.value
    content {
      name = each.key
      type = each.value.db_type
    }
  }
}
```

Error

```
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on database_users.tf line 25, in resource "mongodbatlas_database_user" "user":
│   25:       database_name = each.value.db_name
│     ├────────────────
│     │ each.value is object with 2 attributes
│
│ This object does not have an attribute named "db_name".
╷
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on database_users.tf line 26, in resource "mongodbatlas_database_user" "user":
│   26:       role_name     = each.value.db_role
│     ├────────────────
│     │ each.value is object with 2 attributes
│
│ This object does not have an attribute named "db_role".
╵
╷
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on database_users.tf line 33, in resource "mongodbatlas_database_user" "user":
│   33:       type = each.value.db_type
│     ├────────────────
│     │ each.value is object with 2 attributes
│
│ This object does not have an attribute named "db_type".
╵
```

**PS**: considering the above `flatten value` is not used. How to solve this using the same db_users contents?

**PPS**: I am also okay with using of `flatten value` as long as it serves my purpose.

Comment: Ok, so what is the problem? Did you try using `for_each` or `count` to create your `resource "users" "user"`?

Comment: Also what is `type = "lake"`? Your local `db_users` does not have any `lake` in it?

Comment: Yes I, did try using `for_each` but I did not succeed while trying to get the exact output  as I required as shown in the resource section. the `type = lake` is the type of cluster. so basically if I have a clusterA with `type=cluster` and clusterB `type=lake` both the cluster should be added on the scope of the database.

Comment: "I did not succeed " - is not specific. Can you provide exact code that you tried and the detailed error message you obtained?

Comment: I have updated the question now for your relevance

Comment: Are you sure that this is the code that generates the error? It seems to me to be a different code as `for_each = local.db_users` would lead to a different errors.

Comment: yes this is the same code that I ran just now

Comment: So you are not using your flatten data structure, called `value` at all?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242476/discussion-between-dempti-and-marcin).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `db_users` should be flattened in a different way, namely:

```
locals {
 
    db_users_flat = merge([
    for username, clusters in local.db_users : 
      {
         for clustername, cluster in clusters : 
           "${username}-${clustername}" => {
                 username = username
                 clustername = clustername
                 cluster = cluster
            }
       }
  ]...) # please do NOT remove the dots
 
}
```

then

```
resource "users" "user" {
  for_each = local.db_users_flat
  username = each.value.username
  dynamic "roles" {
    for_each = range(length(each.value.cluster.db_name))
    content {
      database_name = each.value.cluster.db_name[roles.key]
      role_name     = each.value.cluster.db_role[roles.key]
    }
  }
  dynamic "scopes" {
    for_each = range(length(each.value.cluster.db_type))
    content {
      name = each.value.clustername
      type = each.value.cluster.db_type[scopes.key]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, this seems to work but I have few doubts and queries here if you dont mind answering.
In the `type` of scope section how do you associate the value for multiple db_type. (The value added might not be a proper way to pass, I would love your suggestion on that as well)
for example, if my db_type has both values let's say `db_type = [["CLUSTER", "LAKE"], ["CLUSTER", "LAKE"], ["CLUSTER", "LAKE"]]` by this what I mean is, my db_user should have access to db of both `cluster` as well as `lake` at the same time if both the keys are present

Comment: @dempti The answer is based on your example `db_users`. If it has different format of `db_type` then it will not work.

Comment: just tried this value `db_type = [["CLUSTER", "LAKE"], ["CLUSTER", "LAKE"], ["CLUSTER", "LAKE"]]` but it seems to fail with the following error 
```╷
│ Error: Incorrect attribute value type
│
│   on database_users.tf line 143, in resource "mongodbatlas_database_user" "user":
│  143:       type = each.value.cluster.db_type[scopes.key]
│     ├────────────────
│     │ each.value.cluster.db_type is tuple with 3 elements
│
│ Inappropriate value for attribute "type": string required.```
What changes are required if I was to use the value that shared on this comment? I will try as suggested

Comment: Also what does `...` represent on the flatten step?

Comment: @dempti The dots are [argument expantion](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/function-calls#expanding-function-arguments). For new version of `db_type` I would suggest making new question. It will require extra level of flattening, and possibly changing your original data structure.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71293523/terraform-loop-for-each-for-tuple
@Marcin

Comment: really appreciate your help @Marcin
if you could upvote my question as well or edit it as per understanding would be great.