# Terraform loop : for_each for tuple

Tags: terraform, infrastructure-as-code

Reference: [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71291602/terraform-loop-for-each) [Terraform loop : for_each](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71291602/terraform-loop-for-each)

Similar to the question I have few changes which needs to be processed using the same method as well.

**Changes**

The value of `db_type` could be between any of these two

```
db_type = [["CLUSTER", "LAKE"], ["CLUSTER", "LAKE"], ["CLUSTER", "LAKE"]]

OR

db_type = ["CLUSTER", "CLUSTER", "CLUSTER"]
```

In this case, when I try to use the same example ***(changes on db_type only)***, as per the [solution original question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71292582/14714082)  following error is observed

```
╷
│ Error: Incorrect attribute value type
│
│   on database_users.tf line 143, in resource "user" "user":
│  143:       type = each.value.cluster.db_type[scopes.key]
│     ├────────────────
│     │ each.value.cluster.db_type is tuple with 3 elements
│
│ Inappropriate value for attribute "type": string required.
╵
╷
│ Error: Incorrect attribute value type
│
│   on database_users.tf line 143, in resource "user" "user":
│  143:       type = each.value.cluster.db_type[scopes.key]
│     ├────────────────
│     │ each.value.cluster.db_type is tuple with 3 elements
│
│ Inappropriate value for attribute "type": string required.
╵
╷
│ Error: Incorrect attribute value type
│
│   on database_users.tf line 143, in resource "user" "user":
│  143:       type = each.value.cluster.db_type[scopes.key]
│     ├────────────────
│     │ each.value.cluster.db_type is tuple with 3 elements
│
│ Inappropriate value for attribute "type": string required.
```

**Question**: What I actually want? How do I achieve that?

- If I was to change the value of `db_type` as explained above following should be the outcome

```
  # mongodbatlas_database_user.user["test_user2-test_cluster2"] will be created
  + resource "mongodbatlas_database_user" "user" {
      + auth_database_name = "admin"
      + aws_iam_type       = "NONE"
      + id                 = (known after apply)
      + ldap_auth_type     = "NONE"
      + password           = (sensitive value)
      + project_id         = "6216f27d3f350c275ea78efb"
      + username           = "test_user2"
      + x509_type          = "NONE"

      + labels {
          + key   = (known after apply)
          + value = (known after apply)
        }

      + roles {
          + collection_name = (known after apply)
          + database_name   = "db_d"
          + role_name       = "readWrite"
        }
      + roles {
          + collection_name = (known after apply)
          + database_name   = "db_e"
          + role_name       = "readWrite"
        }
      + roles {
          + collection_name = (known after apply)
          + database_name   = "db_f"
          + role_name       = "read"
        }

      + scopes {
          + name = "test_cluster2"
          + type = "CLUSTER"
        }
      + scopes {
          + name = "test_cluster2"
          + type = "LAKE"
        }
    }
```

If the value of `db_type = [["CLUSTER", "LAKE"], ["CLUSTER", "LAKE"], ["CLUSTER", "LAKE"]]`, the **Expected Output** should be

```
Resource No. 1

username=test_user1
role = {
  db_name=db_a
  role=readWrite
}
role = {
  db_name=db_b
  role=read
}
role = {
  db_name=db_c
  role=readWrite
}
scope = {
  name = test_cluster1
  type = "cluster"
}
scope = {
  name = test_cluster1
  type = "lake"
}

Resource No. 2

username=test_user1
role = {
  db_name=db_d
  role=readWrite
}
role = {
  db_name=db_e
  role=read
}
role = {
  db_name=db_f
  role=readWrite
}
scope = {
  name = test_cluster2
  type = "cluster"
}
scope = {
  name = test_cluster2
  type = "lake"
}
...
```

If the value of `db_type = db_type = ["CLUSTER", "CLUSTER", "CLUSTER"]`, the **Expected Output** should be

```
Resource No. 1

username=test_user1
role = {
  db_name=db_a
  role=readWrite
}
role = {
  db_name=db_b
  role=read
}
role = {
  db_name=db_c
  role=readWrite
}
scope = {
  name = test_cluster1
  type = "cluster"
}

Resource No. 2

username=test_user1
role = {
  db_name=db_d
  role=readWrite
}
role = {
  db_name=db_e
  role=read
}
role = {
  db_name=db_f
  role=readWrite
}
scope = {
  name = test_cluster2
  type = "cluster"
}
...
```

Comment: It would be much easier if db could be `db_type = [["CLUSTER"], ["CLUSTER"], ["CLUSTER"]]`. This way you have list of lists, rather then variable data type, which I'm not sure you could easily worked with.

Comment: yeah that would be easier, but there are cases where the db_type can be both in order to provide access to multiple type of cluster to the same database users which is why this situation might occur as well. since the solution mostly handles the `cluster`, it also needs to handle the `lake` as well for same user.

Comment: You should work with TF data types rather then against it. Your data structures and requirements are not suited for TF. They may be fine in other languages, but in TF its very complex to work with random data types.

Comment: Also this new `db_type` is always in pairs? Or you can have: `[["CLUSTER", "LAKE"], ["LAKE"], ["CLUSTER", "LAKE", "OCEAN"]]` ?

Comment: can you suggest me a proper methods.
This is the one which I am asking you a solution for https://registry.terraform.io/providers/mongodb/mongodbatlas/latest/docs/resources/database_user

Comment: So in case of `[["CLUSTER", "LAKE"], ["CLUSTER", "LAKE"], ["CLUSTER", "LAKE"]]` there would be six scopes in a given cluster?

Comment: No, for a single database user there can be two scopes either `cluster` only or `lake` or both `lake and cluster`

Comment: Sadly I don't understand what should happen if you have `[["CLUSTER", "LAKE"], ["LAKE"], ["CLUSTER", "LAKE", "OCEAN"]]`. Maybe you can update your question with expected resources generated like before?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242481/discussion-between-dempti-and-marcin).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, its better to use `db_users` in the following form:

```
  db_users = {
    test_user1 = {      #user
      test_cluster1 = { #cluster
        db_name = ["db_a", "db_b", "db_c"]
        db_role = ["readWrite", "read", "readWrite"]
        db_type = [["CLUSTER"], ["CLUSTER"], ["CLUSTER"]]
      },
      test_cluster2 = {
        db_name = ["db_a", "db_b", "db_c"]
        db_role = ["readWrite", "read", "readWrite"]
        db_type = [["CLUSTER"], ["CLUSTER"], ["CLUSTER"]]
      }
    },
    test_user2 = {
      test_cluster1 = {
        db_name = ["db_d", "db_e", "db_f"]
        db_role = ["readWrite", "readWrite", "read"]
        db_type = [["CLUSTER", "LAKE"], ["CLUSTER", "LAKE"], ["CLUSTER", "LAKE"]]
      },
      test_cluster2 = {
        db_name = ["db_d", "db_e", "db_f"]
        db_role = ["readWrite", "readWrite", "read"]
        db_type = [["CLUSTER"], ["CLUSTER"], ["CLUSTER"]]
      }
    }
  }
```

then you flatten as:

```
  
  db_users_flat = merge(flatten([
    for username, clusters in local.db_users : 
      [
         for clustername, cluster in clusters : 
         {
             for idx, db_types in cluster.db_type: 
                 "${username}-${clustername}-${idx}" => {
                       username = username
                       clustername = clustername
                       cluster = {
                         db_name = cluster.db_name
                         db_role = cluster.db_role
                         db_type = db_types
                       }
                  }
               }
       ]
  ])...)
```

and use as:

```
resource "users" "user" {
    for_each = local.db_users_flat
    username = each.value.username
    dynamic "roles" {
      for_each = range(length(each.value.cluster.db_name))
      content {
        database_name = each.value.cluster.db_name[roles.key]
        role_name     = each.value.cluster.db_role[roles.key]
      }
    }
    dynamic "scopes" {
      for_each = range(length(each.value.cluster.db_type))
      content {
        name = each.value.clustername
        type = each.value.cluster.db_type[scopes.key]
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi.
Thank you it works.
Could you explain the for loop for future reference (mostly the usage of `[` at some place and `{` at some place.

Also is it possible to make this value `test_user2-test_cluster1-1` to only replace it as per `db_username`

Comment: @dempti Glad it works. There are 3 for loops as you need three levels of flattening. So you end up with a `list of lists of maps` (thus `{` in the most inner loop). The you flatten it into `list of maps`, and finally the `...` changes it to a simple `map` which is suited for `for_each`.

Comment: I just noted there might be a bug on the answer.
It should have created 4 usrs in total, but it is creating 12 users in total
I have dmd the info on the discussion https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242481/discussion-between-dempti-and-marcin

Comment: all the necessary files are here


https://pastebin.com/j1gREdVg -> terraform plan
https://pastebin.com/d98TamYu -> db_users
https://pastebin.com/uzXT7Jfp -> original output.tf
https://pastebin.com/JSdr8Pvk -> expected output.tf